# Freeform replacement in EE5

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

Looking for a Freeform replacement for EE5 - as I understand it Freeform (my usual go-to) is now a commercial add-on so looking for a replacement/equivalent solution. Does not need tons of complex functionality - just basic fields and an anti-Spam Captcha capability.

What is the - free - add-on of choice here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a free alternative for the freeform add-on.

A simpler alternative would be to use [FormGrab](https://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/formgrab) from [brandnewbox](https://brandnewbox.co.uk/) which currently is free, but appears to be licensed as a commercial product - which provides the ability to turn regular HTML forms into ones that talk to the EE database.

FormGrab does not have a captcha module built in, but although not free if you want this you are much better off spending USD29 on a copy of [snaptcha](https://putyourlightson.com/expressionengine-addons/snaptcha) - a very simple to use add-on that provides good spam protection without any visible captcha fields.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [*Express* edition of Freeform](https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/freeform), which allows for 1 simpler form with a lot of the advanced functionality available to it. It's not free, but it's $49 compared to $99 for the *Lite* edition. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use forms with basic EE functionality, like Channel Form.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/overview.html

Basically create a channel, then allow users on your website to add/edit to it, using forms.

If it's a contact form you're looking for, EE also has a native solution.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email.html

You could use reCAPTCHA for free as anti-spam.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

FreeForm Pro combines all of that conveniently, but if you're looking to save money and your needs are minimal, you can use those other methods.